# Give an element a width when display:none;

Tags: jquery, css

I have a little CSS transition that I want to use to have an element slide out from behind its parent.

Element:

```
#contact-form{
    background: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    top:-20em;
    display:none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 2em 0;
    width:100%;

    -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: top 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: top 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: top 0.2s ease;
    transition: top 0.2s ease;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#contactBtn').click(function(){
    $('#contact-form').css('top', 0).toggle('display');
});
```

As you might have guessed, this results in the element sliding in from the top-left corner, rather than just from the top (because when the element is "display none" it doesn't have a width).

What's the best way to ensure the transition ONLY targets the height of the element, rather than the width as well? It needs to start at top:-20 because it is attached to a navbar that appears halfway down the page.

Comment: Note: `-moz-transition` is no longer needed, and `-ms-transition` and `-o-transiton` never existed.

Comment: You change the height of the element instead of toggling display, because like you said, an element with `display: none` doesn't have a width.

Comment: @Kolink Really? I just took them from here: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/ CSS-Tricks has always seemed like a credible source

Comment: Yup, really. I use [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition) as my source of information, but the general rule at this time is that Chrome is way behind the times.

Comment: @Jascination: That was last updated half a year ago.

Comment: @BoltClock I tried that but it only changed the background (parent) element and not the contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
$("#contact-form").slideToggle();
```

Perhaps this example will help: http://jsfiddle.net/dJS4g/

Comment: It overrides the browser's default behavior. In this case, it cancels the browser’s default behavior of visiting the href of the anchor tag.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm using it on a button so I won't need that, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

See if this can make your work.

```
div
{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/jsdev/pen/nrKBi

```
$('#contactBtn').click(function(){
  $('#contact-form').css({
    top: 0,
    height: ''
  });
});

$('#closeContactBtn').click(function(){
    $('#contact-form').css({
      top: '',
      height: 0
    });
});
```

you don't need to set width 100% on your form